# Mysql delete query forgetting the Id constraint

Tags: mysql

I run a wrong delete query in mysql terminal which i terminated quickly. however, i would like to know the likely outcome.

```
delete from table where 123
```

instead of

```
delete from table where id=123
```

Comment: Simple answer is you can't replace `where 123` for `where id=123`.. `where 123` will be rewritten to `where 1` in MySQL database which means **always** true see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j1deYcdAAH8mFzfTeihLXi/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WHERE clause expects a *boolean* expression (something that is either TRUE or FALSE). If the expression is not *boolean*, it will be casted to a numeric value. Then any numeric value which is not equal to `0` (zero) is considered to be TRUE. Zero or NULL are equivalent to FALSE.

Since `123` is a non-zero numeric value, `WHERE 123` is equivalent to `WHERE 1` or `WHERE TRUE` (or even just without the WHERE clause), which in you case means: Delete all rows in the table.

Beside that: Some clients have settings, which don't permit delete statements like this, and expect the primary key to be used in the WHERE clause. Those settings are introduced to avoid exactly this kind of (typo) errors. To delete all rows, you would then need to write `WHERE id=id`.

Answer (score 1):

It will delete all the rows of the table. MySQL treats all the integer from 1 to 9 as true and 0 as false. So now the where clause will give the boolean true result.

Answer (score 0):

To see what query will delete, you can run same query but with `select` clause, like:

```
select * from table where 123
```

in this particular case it must select **all rows** without any filtering.